why autoregressive models can't do representation learning(unsupervised learning)?
I was going through the lecture-4 of the deep generative modelling course from Cornell. In the lecture slides it is mentions that autoregressive models cannot do representation learning(min: 5.23). Could you please elaborate on this ?
lecture link: lecture-4
